# JSON Payload ingested into MySQL database using Mule ESB

Tags: mysql, json, mule, esb

I'm making a webservice call and retrieving a json payload as such:

```
   [
     {
       "type": " --T::00"
     },
     {
    "address": "10049 College Way N",
    "longitude": "-122.335022",
    "latitude": "47.701756",
    "incident_number": "F110104009",
    "type": "Aid Response",
    "report_location": {
        "needs_recoding": false,
        "longitude": "-122.335022",
        "latitude": "47.701756"
      }
      },
      {
    "address": "5929 Beach Dr Sw",
    "longitude": "-122.397816",
    "latitude": "47.550431",
    "incident_number": "F110104008",
    "type": "Aid Response",
    "report_location": {
        "needs_recoding": false,
        "longitude": "-122.397816",
        "latitude": "47.550431"
     }
     }
```

I'm iterating through each line and ingesting key values into a MySQl DB table. I expect the first value 'type -t00' to be inserted with incident_number, longitude, latitude to be blank. However in every subsequent iteration, I expect the ingestion to work. Instead, I get the following:

```
    ID Longitude Latitude incident_number type      
    1     null        null    null      --T::00
    65    null        null    null      1RED 1 Unit
    70    null        null    null      1RED 1 Unit
    313   null        null    null      1RED 1 Unit
    314   null        null    null      1RED 1 Unit
    315   null        null    null      1RED 1 Unit
    316   null        null    null      1RED 1 Unit
```

What is happening is that only the type is being ingested properly from the JSON payload but every other payload value is null. As I debug, I do see the iteration and can clearly identify the payload.incident_number, payload.longitude but it seems to me that the problem is ingested. I've tried ingesting only the incident_number but that comes as null in the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My configuration.xml below:

```
       <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="demo"              
        password="Welcome1" database="demo" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>

  <flow name="seattleemergencyFlow1" doc:name="seattleemergencyFlow1"> 
       <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8900"  
       path="get-emergency" doc:name="HTTP"></http:inbound-endpoint>  

      <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="data.seattle.gov"   
       port="80" path="resource/kzjm-xkqj.json?" method="GET" contentType="application/json" 
       doc:name="HTTP"></http:outbound-endpoint>  

      <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"> 
      </json:json-to-object-transformer>

       <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO emergencyrecords
       (incident_number, type, longitude)
         VALUES
       ( 
         #[payload.incident_number],
         #[payload.type],
         #[payload.longitude])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
       </foreach>

      </flow>

     </mule>
```

Comment: Sorry David..Just learning the forum. I've done so on of my prior questions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `<foreach collection="#[message.payload]" doc:name="For Each">` as following:-

```
     <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="demo"              
        password="Welcome1" database="demo" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>

  <flow name="seattleemergencyFlow1" doc:name="seattleemergencyFlow1"> 
       <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8900"  
       path="get-emergency" doc:name="HTTP"></http:inbound-endpoint>  

      <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="data.seattle.gov"   
       port="80" path="resource/kzjm-xkqj.json?" method="GET" contentType="application/json" 
       doc:name="HTTP"></http:outbound-endpoint>  

      <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"> 
      </json:json-to-object-transformer>

        <foreach collection="#[message.payload]" doc:name="For Each">
        <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO emergencyrecords
       (incident_number, type, longitude)
         VALUES
       ( 
         #[payload.incident_number],
         #[payload.type],
         #[payload.longitude])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
       </foreach>

      </flow>

     </mule>
```

It was strange as only **type** value was returned and remaining value was null ..
but when I removed the **type** from json like the following :-

```
[

     {
    "address": "10049 College Way N",
    "longitude": "-122.335022",
    "latitude": "47.701756",
    "incident_number": "F110104009",
    "type": "Aid Response",
    "report_location": {
        "needs_recoding": false,
        "longitude": "-122.335022",
        "latitude": "47.701756"
      }
      },
      {
    "address": "5929 Beach Dr Sw",
    "longitude": "-122.397816",
    "latitude": "47.550431",
    "incident_number": "F110104008",
    "type": "Aid Response",
    "report_location": {
        "needs_recoding": false,
        "longitude": "-122.397816",
        "latitude": "47.550431"
     }
     }
  ]
```

I got all the values of `payload.incident_number` and `payload.longitude` etc ..

It may be the reason that since

```
    {
       "type": " --T::00"
     }
```

is present at the **beginning** in the JSON it's only taking the value of **"`type":`** as a list from all the values

So... The suggested solution is use the following format :-

```
[

     {
    "address": "10049 College Way N",
    "longitude": "-122.335022",
    "latitude": "47.701756",
    "incident_number": "F110104009",
    "type": "Aid Response",
    "report_location": {
        "needs_recoding": false,
        "longitude": "-122.335022",
        "latitude": "47.701756"
      }
      },
      {
    "address": "5929 Beach Dr Sw",
    "longitude": "-122.397816",
    "latitude": "47.550431",
    "incident_number": "F110104008",
    "type": "Aid Response",
    "report_location": {
        "needs_recoding": false,
        "longitude": "-122.397816",
        "latitude": "47.550431"
     }
     },

      {
           "type": " --T::00"
       }   
  ]
```

by keeping **"type"** at the end .. you will get all the values as expected ..

Comment: Thanks Anirban...That's in the response JSON payload from the service. Anyway I can ignore it in Mule?

Comment: You can ignore and take the value whatever you like in Mule using Mule expression that you are using now  .. And If you could able to format the JSON as I mentioned , you could get your expected result ... Anyways if you find the answer useful ..please accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks Anirban...What would would be the Mule expression to ignore the root node of the JSON payload? Is there a ignore #[payload.type[0}]?

Comment: Appreciate your answer but I still have the same issue. How do I ignore the root note and post the "type" at the end as you suggest? I've no control over the response that is sent to me from the webservice